# Flask error initializing database

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I'm following the Flask [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/) to try to make my own thing. I'm getting an error in [step 5](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbinit/) when I try to initialize the database.

When I type `flask initdb` into terminal, this is the error I get:
seei5.py
line 24, in init_db
db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "drop": syntax error

I'm using python 3.6

This is my file structure:

```
/seei5
    /seei5
        __init__.py
        /static
        /templates
        seei5.py
        schema.sql
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in
```

MANIFEST.in

```
graft seei5/templates
graft seei5/static
include seei5/schema.sql
```

schema.sql

```
drop table if exists books;
create table books (
    book_id integer,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id))


drop table if exists chapters;
create table chapters (
    chapter_id integer,
    chapter text,
    book_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (chapter_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id))


drop table if exists concepts;
create table concepts (
    concepts_id integer,
    concept text,
    definition text,
    chapter_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (concepts_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (chapter_id) REFERENCES chapters (chapter_id))
```

seei5.py

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'seei5.db'),
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('SEEI5_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
    return rv

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    init_db()
    print("Initialized the database.")

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you fix your `schema.sql`

**schema.sql**

```
drop table if exists books;
create table books (
    book_id integer,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id));


drop table if exists chapters;
create table chapters (
    chapter_id integer,
    chapter text,
    book_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (chapter_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id));


drop table if exists concepts;
create table concepts (
    concepts_id integer,
    concept text,
    definition text,
    chapter_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (concepts_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (chapter_id) REFERENCES chapters (chapter_id));
```

You have missing `;`